# Getting Type Mismatch error in vba selenium

Tags: vba, selenium-webdriver

In below code I'm getting below error at `Set H2Headers = ch.FindElementByTag("h2")`:

*Run-time error 13: Type mismatch*

```
Private ch As Selenium.ChromeDriver

Sub TestSelenium()
    
    Set ch = New Selenium.ChromeDriver
    
    ch.Start
    ch.Get "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page"
    
    Dim H2Headers As Selenium.WebElements
    
    Set H2Headers = ch.FindElementByTag("h2")
    
    Debug.Print H2Headers.Count

End Sub
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try _FindElement**s**ByTag_ instead of FindElementByTag.

Comment: Thanks a lot, you may post it as an answer. It's working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worked with below change:

`FindElementsByTag` instead of `FindElementByTag`